# Ionic v4 + firestore authentication

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm trying to develop a small ionic v4 hybrid app. The app should contain a login and authentication. Ionic v4 provides the whole routing package of angular. So I want to use this routing technique and firestore to make an authentication with login and so on for my app.
My problem is, that I'm really new to both and I don't figure the best practices out. Does somebody have any suggestions or experiance? That would help alot.

I made a few researches and tried some stuff. These two links were the most usefull in my opinion:
Firebase authentication with Ionic v3: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/firebase-authentication-in-ionic-framework-apps
Ionic v4 authentication: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-login-angular/

Perhaps it's really easy, but I don't get how to get them together and where firestore saves the users... Do I get a token from firestore authentication?

The final goal is to have a firestore collection with all users. It contains their password, settings and so on.

If a user is logged in he could route over private user specific pages and if he's not he should only see public stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit broad and it has a lot of steps for you to enable the Authentication in firebase in your application, but to get you started, I suggest for you to watch this series all about [Authentication in Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jUPIes_B8vRjn1_GaplOPQ) although its in javascript and HTML but the main concepts are the same,

To answer some of your questions.

1. You need to enable first the Authentication in your project by going to the Authentication tab of your Firebase Console
2. When you enable it you may choose what type of authentication you want to use, in the tutorial link I mentioned they used the Email and Password
3. After enabling it, you need to reference Firebase in your application so you may use its functions within your app
4. You may add users by using the proper method given by Firebase to store it in Firebase, for email and password authentication we use `firebasereference.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("username","password")` firebase automatically creates a UserID for you with this
5. Firebase automatically handles the authentication process, to signin we just use the `firebasereference.signInWithEmailAndPassword("usename,"password")`
6. The Authentication contains minimal information we can store so you need to combine firestore/realtimedatabase with Authentication to store Users data like isAdmin, Address and Name, typically we use the same userID generated by the Authentication when storing user documents in the user's collection.
7. Firestore does not store the password. it is all handled by Google Authentication, in fact you can't even see the passwords inputed by the users as the Authentication handles all of it, you can just delete the account or reset the password.

Please take note that the method I have said provides a Promise so you should wait for the response to check the value returned by firebase, In javascript, we use .then() to signify the next steps once the results come back.

The tutorial I have mentioned above will pretty much teach you all that you need based on your questions

P.s. I'm not an Ionic dev but a bit of google tells me that it uses Javascript and HTML to create apps, so I think the tutorial will provide you with a lot of information!. Good Luck!

Comment: Great thanks for the fast answer. I will watch the tutorial and hopefully get to my goal. If not I will ask again about more specific topics :D

Comment: sure, just let others know if the answer helped you in any way :)

Comment: The tutorial is all I needed in my case. I just changed some small things so thank you :D